# NonLinearModelFit with errors on x axis?

Tags: fitting

[Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/FitModelsWithMeasurementErrors.html) it is explained how to do a non linear model fit of data with measurement errors on y axis.

Is there a way to do a non linear fit of data including errors on the x axis? i.e. How to include errors on x axis data in NonLinearModelFit?

Comment: Nonlinear total least squares is a much harder problem than the ordinary version, and definitely not yet supported by `NonlinearModelFit[]`.

Answer (score 1):

So, like [J.M pointed out in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136205/nonlinearmodelfit-with-errors-on-x-axis#comment367565_136205) there is no possible solution when you have BOTH x and y errors. 
BUT you can sometimes do something if you have x errors but negligible y errors.
You just parameterize from $y(x)$ to $x(y)$ and fit it that way with your normal weights.

I made an example for you:

We make a fit for the function $y(x)=a\exp\left(b\cdot x\right)$

Lets make some random points:

```
function = a*Exp[b*x];
range = {{0, 1}, {0, 6}};
n = 30;
xErrors = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1], n];
data = Table[{i/n + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]*xErrors[[i]], 
    function /. {x -> (i/n), a -> 2, b -> 1}}, {i, 1, n}];
(*create random data*)
```

Now we solve for $x(y)$

```
sol = (x /. 
    Refine[Solve[function == y, x, Reals], 
     a > 0 && y > 0]); (*solve the function for y*)
```

$=\log(y/a)/b$

We reorder our data from $(x,y)$ to $(y,x)$ and do the weighted fits with instrumental-weights: $p_i=\delta_i^{-2}$

```
subData = Reverse /@ data; (*remap our data (x,y)\[Rule](y,x)*)
subFit = NonlinearModelFit[subData, Re@sol, {a, b}, y, 
  Weights -> 1/xErrors^2]; (*fit for x(y)*)
```

In the end we can plot this with and without weighted fits:

```
Legended[Show[
  ListPlot[data],
  Plot[
   {Evaluate@(NonlinearModelFit[data, function, {a, b}, x][
       "BestFit"]), (*fit unweighted with y(x)*)
    function /. 
     subFit["BestFitParameters"]}, (*use parameterized fit from x(y)*)
   {x, range[[1, 1]], range[[1, 2]]}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}], 
  PlotRange -> range]
 , LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"unweighted", "weighted"}]]
```

which gives us the graph:

[image]

Comment: "no possible solution" - I didn't exactly say that. :D One could certainly write a routine for this kind of fitting, but it's complicated and delicate enough to implement that I'd prolly ask to get paid first.

Comment: Just to attempt to add to what @J.M. has stated:  it's much, much harder and complex than when the predictor variables are measured without error.  And it's not just providing a different fitting algorithm.  It involves what assumptions about the errors one can make (and not just willing to make).